# PHP fopen() memory usage while Merging many files together

Tags: php, fopen

I have many file chunks and I need to merge them using PHP fopen function.However, I'm worring  about the memory usage.
For example,I got about 100 files listed in `split_hash.txt`,each is about 100mb. And here I combine them together:

```
<?php  
$hash = file_get_contents("split_hash.txt");  
$list = explode("\r\n",$hash);  
$fp = fopen("hadoop2.zip","ab"); 
foreach($list as $value){  
    if(!empty($value)) {  
        $handle = fopen($value,"rb");  
        fwrite($fp,fread($handle,filesize($value)));  
        fclose($handle);  
        unset($handle);  
    }  
}  
fclose($fp);  
echo "ok";
```

Will it cost a lot of my memory?

Comment: I feel your biggest challenge is going to be script execution time.

Comment: Will it  cost a lot of time? I'm working on handling chunking upload,so it must to be fast.

Comment: that is going to be dependant on your infrastructure, a server with data on local SSD's for example is going to be fast to perform file system acations. I think you're just going to have to try it to see how long it takes to process 100 files times by 100mb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will it cost a lot of my memory?

it will if you use `fread($handle,filesize($value))` to get the whole length of the file for your fread, use fread in smaller chunks per file.

I would change:

```
fwrite($fp,fread($handle,filesize($value)));
```

to:

```
while (!feof($handle)) {
    fwrite($fp,fread($handle,1048576));  
}
```

so that you are only dealing with 10 megabytes at a time

Answer (score 0):

It will cost you the maximum of your 100 file size in memory peak.

you are reading whole file and write it to another file. In this case it doesn't matter how many files do you have, but it matters how big is file.

You are saying it's ~100 mb, with default php settings it's 128 mb memory limit, which is acceptable for your case